# check if a div inside iframe is visible in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe, visible

I have an iframe named article_frame with several DIVs, named article_disp_0, article_disp_1, etc.
Only one of these is visible at a time.

When I'm outside the iframe, I want to be able to see which one is visible, so I have a script that is like this:

```
// find the currently selected article
for (i=0; i<=a_count; i++) {
    a_disp = "#article_disp_" + i;
    frame_disp = $('#article_frame').contents().find(a_disp);
    visible = frame_disp.is(':visible');
    if (visible) {
        art_div = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

That all works just fine in Chrome or Safari, but not in Firefox.  It appears that the visible value is not getting set when in Firefox.  So what do I need to do to make this work with Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

then

```
visible = $(innerDoc.getElementById("your ID")).is(':visible');
```

Comment: OK, I tried that, and it worked fine in Safari, but still not in Firefox.  Here's what I've got now: 

var iframe = document.getElementById('article_frame');`
    `var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;`
 
    `// find the currently selected article`
  for (i=0; i<=a_count; i++) {
   a_disp = "article_disp_" + i;
   visible = $(innerDoc.getElementById(a_disp)).is(':visible');
   
   if (visible) {
    art_div = i;
    break;
   }
  }
`

Comment: 1. Are you getting a DIV object reference to test the visibility on?
2. Can u try testing its style.display or style.visibility property?

Comment: Yes, I actually did this, and it works.
`
    disp = $(innerDoc.getElementById(a_disp)).css('display');
    
    if (disp == "block") // found the visible one
`
Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: @abbaroo you're welcome, if this solution helped you please take the time to "Accept" my answer.